# Creating an ordinal vector in R

Tags: r, vector, statistics

I have a vector  y_1  wit values from 0-100.I need to do this vector ordinal
I need to code this:

```
Y=1 if y_1 <=20

    Y=2 if y_1 between 20 and 40
    Y=3 if y_1 between 40 and 60
    Y=4 if y_1 between 60 and 80
    Y=5 if y_1 > 80
```

I tried this but I can't name ordinal categories:

```
findInterval(y_1, c(0,20,40,60,80))
 cut(y_1, breaks=c(0,20, 40, 60, 80, 100),ordered_result=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your vector.

```
y_1 <- 0:100
```

First, let's define the thresholds for the split.

```
vectorThresholds <- c(20, 40, 60, 80, Inf)
```

Then, we can define a new vector containing a number corresponding to the interval.

```
y_2 <- sapply(y_1, function(el){
  min(which(el < vectorThresholds))
})
```

In order to name the levels, you can just use factor.

```
y_3 <- factor(y_2, labels = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `-Inf` and `Inf` you can define the "edge" cases more "inclusifvely":

```
> table(cut(y_1, c(-Inf,20,40,60,80, Inf), rightmost.closed=TRUE) )

(-Inf,20]   (20,40]   (40,60]   (60,80] (80, Inf] 
       21        20        20        20        20
```

This also leaves clear that the right sides of the intervals are closed (which your question only hinted at as your expectation).